# Qt Android App can't connect to internet via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: android, json, qt, ssl

This is a strange habit that I have no clue how to fix it. Here's what happen.

- Qt android app's been written (mainly using QML, the complicated calculation part's been written in C++) and everything works perfectly on one phone/tablet but 
  not on the others.
- It works on android phone/tablet version 5 (lollipop) but seemingly not on android version 6 (marshmallow).
- What's not working is the part that I read JSON data from Thingspeak
  using JavaScript's XMLHttpRequest. As mentioned above, it works perfectly
  on one phone/tablet but not on the others.
- The only clue I have on the not-working phone/tablet is this

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_free

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_rc2_cbc

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_get_builtin_curves

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_curve_nist2nid

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function EC_get_builtin_curves

qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function EC_get_builtin_curves

- hence, reading JSON part gave "JSON.parse: Parse error"
- Qt , as I understand, take care of all the basic modules and permissions into the app. So I doubt it would be Internet permission but how could some of the phone/tablets are working just fine. That's I'm
  wonder. Anyone might have some experience on this to share...
- Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a little clue...

[From here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)

> Android is moving away from OpenSSL to the BoringSSL library. If you’re using the Android NDK in your app, don't link against cryptographic libraries that are not a part of the NDK API, such as libcrypto.so and libssl.so. These libraries are not public APIs, and may change or break without notice across releases and devices. In addition, you may expose yourself to security vulnerabilities. Instead, modify your native code to call the Java cryptography APIs via JNI or to statically link against a cryptography library of your choice.